# Bitcoin mining software for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, bitcoin

I'm looking for a Bitcoin miner that meets these requirements

- Compatiable with Windows 10
- Uses either or both the CPU and GPU to mine
- Gratis

Some features that are not requirements but wanted are,

- GUI interface
- Collects some basic statistics (like how many MB per sec it's mining)

Comment: you could use the 50 miner front end with a cg miner backend

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have heard this over and over again, but I'll say it myself: Bitcoin mining with your CPU will not earn you money. However, if you want to try, [minerd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpuminer/) (your computer will detect it as a virus, but it's not). It works pretty well on other coins too, although I am not sure if it does Bitcoin (it should, as it has SHA256). I recorded a video tutorial on how to mine Dogecoin with it, and that link is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1bD9VNhMKU&t=13s). Just use the steps I did, except download a bitcoin wallet, request a bitcoin transaction, and set the algorithm to SHA256, not scrypt. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, more accurately, it will not earn you money unless someone else is paying your electric bill. ;-)